# Task.WaitAll on a list in F#

Tags: list, f#, functional-programming, parallel-extensions

I am doing parallel programming using F#. With fixed number of elements, for example with 2 elements a1, a2 and a function f, I can do as follows:

```
let t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> f a1)
let t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> f a2)
Task.WaitAll(t1, t2)
t1.Result, t2.Result
```

I wonder how I could do the same with a list of elements:

```
let ts = List.map (fun a -> Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> f a))
Task.WaitAll(ts)
List.map (fun (t: Task<_>) -> t.Result) ts
```

Visual Studio spots that Task.WaitAll couldn't accept Task< T > list as its parameter. Task.WaitAll can have Task [] as its argument but it makes no sense because I need to get Result for next computation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Robert explains, if you want to call `WaitAll`, you'll have to cast the elements sequence to the base type `Task` and then convert it to an array. You can define your extension member for `Task` to make the tas simpler:

```
type System.Threading.Tasks.Task with
  static member WaitAll(ts) =
    Task.WaitAll [| for t in ts -> t :> Task |]
```

I'm using array comprehension and cast instead of `Seq.cast` because `Seq.cast` takes untyped `IEnumerable` - so F# infers better type for the extension method.

Another option is not to call `WaitAll` at all - if you don't do it, the `Result` properties will block until a task completes. This means that you'll block the thread anyway (there may be a bit larger number of blockings, but I'm not sure if it affects performance too much). If you use `List.map` to collect all results, the behavior would be almost the same.

Answer (score 6):

This is an unfortunate design. Task.WaitAll is using the c# params keyword to allow you to specify several arguments and have them be an array in the method. It also uses C#'s implicit casting so that you can give it `Task<T>`'s.
In F# you have to do this yourself by casting explicitly and converting to array:

```
let ts = [| 
     Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> 1)
     Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> 2)
     |]
Task.WaitAll(ts |> Seq.cast<Task> |> Array.ofSeq)
```

Now you can get the results from `ts`.

Answer (score 1):

Array also has map, so there's no reason you can't put the tasks in an array.

Or you could convert to an array just for the waitall...